# json encoded arrays from php loop using jquery

Tags: json

I have errors from the server as JSON but can seem to loop through the errors with jquery.ere is a glance of my errors from the server(`{"errors":["the firstname can not be left blank","the lastnamecan not be left blank"]}`)can someone please tell me how i can loop through this json in jquery..thanks

Comment: Please edit your errors so that they are not a part of plain text; it makes it easier for us to read

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: {"errors":
        
        ["the firstname can not be left blank",
        "the lastnamecan not be left blank"]
        
        }